# Database using MS Access

Tags: relational-database

When we declare a composite key (two columns for the primary key in table1) and link one of the columns of the primary key to another table2. Why we declare these primary key in general section indexed --> yes (Duplicate ok). I am confuse for what reason Duplicate data entry is ok while it is a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> primary key to another table

it is a foriegn key. That key maybe duplicate but not main primary key be repeated.A foreign key is a field in one table that is a primary key in another table.